# Prism dependency injection lifecycle issue

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, prism

I'm trying to inject my rest API dependencies into my frontend WPF application.

So far, I want to inject 2 different objects based on same the interface, it works perfectly this way, I manage to get my 2 repositories where I need to get them.

```
            containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IBaseRepository, Foo1>("a")
                .RegisterSingleton<IBaseRepository, Foo2>("b");
```

My issue is that for optimization purpose, I do not think it's appropriate to have them registered as Singletons (as they would live the whole life cycle of my application), `Register` isn't an option either.
My ideal choice would be to use `RegisterScoped` as I think that a scoped lifetime is the best here but I cannot see any way to do it.

Am I misunderstanding the real lifecycle of DI Singletons in Prism and it's actually the classic way to do it or is there a way to do an equivalent of what I did here but in the limit of my scope ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's no such thing as `lifecycle of DI Singletons in Prism` - dependency injection in Prism is just a wrapper around the actual container with no defined behavior of its own. Thus, you should add which container you're using.

Comment: Also, you should define what's the scope you desire. The "normal" scope is per request in an asp net environment.

Comment: @Haukinger When I'm talking about lifecycle, I mean that an object doesn't keep its state through the whole life of an application, Register means Transient, Singleton means an object that "that retains it state throughout the lifecycle of your application" according to the prism documentation. https://prismlibrary.com/docs/dependency-injection/registering-types.html

Comment: Why is `Register` not an option?  What is wrong with it?  Seems like it's exactly what you want.

Comment: @Joe It's the first time I'm working with dependency injections in .Net so I'm not an expert but from what my senior dev team mate explained me and from what I've read from prism documentation, I got that the object will get killed after each request as it's transient, and it doesn't seem optimized in our case to have it instancied over again and again. But maybe there is something I am missing here...

Comment: Well that all depends on how you implement the object.  How expensive is it to initialize?  If it is expensive, is there some part of it that could be turned into one-time initialization that could be cached (e.g. statically) and then each transient instance could then access?

Comment: The app will have to manage hundreds of thousands service calls and will be used by hundreds of users. That's why Register is not an option. I've seen that Unity offers multi threading and DryIoc offers the possibility to open and close our own scope, those seem to be 2 good options to get to an well optimized point.